# Error accessing class when using Composer autoloader

Tags: php, namespaces, autoloader

I have folder app/Controllers/HomeController.php and in my composer autoloader i write like this:

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
        }
    },
```

but when i try to access my file from public/index.php like this:

```
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$home = new \App\Controllers\HomeController;
```

I got some error like this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'HomeController' not found in E:\laragon\www\slim\public\index.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in E:\laragon\www\slim\public\index.php on line 14
```

so where i'm doing wrong here? for more info in my HomeController i using namespace like this:

```
namespace App\Controllers;
```

Comment: Do you have the correct namespace and class name in the actual controller? Also, why is `App` under `autoload-dev` and not just `autoload`?

Comment: yes in my HomeController i put namespace App\Controllers; and yes i was about going to move it to autoload. it just for temporary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the answer is I have to dumb my autoloader and it works.